# Viajar vs. viajarse?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I am not clear as to the distinction between *viajar* and *viajarse*. When would each be used? To say "We will be traveling for a few months," I would say "Nos viajaremos unos meses," but I don't know why it couldn't be simply "Viajaremos unos meses."

Comment: I'm not expert but I couldn't see "viajarse" in the RAE dictionary.  But I did see examples in spanishdict that used the infinitive to describe something as a mode of transportation.  Could this be a regionalism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"nos viajamos" no es una form de "viajarse", sino un uso de "se" llamado "dativo superfluo", o "dativo ético" que sirve como un complemento que se interesa vivamente en la realización de la acción expresada por el verbo. Puede omitirse sin pérdida de información. Es prescindible. Ejemplos:

- Nosotros nos leímos la novela de un tirón.
- Juan se comió tres platos de arroz.
- Se fue de repente.
- Se pasó todo un año descansando.
- No se esperaba eso.
- Juan se construyó un hermoso chalé en la Sierra.
- Los alumnos se temen lo peor.
- Juan se merece un premio.
- ¿Cuántas cervezas te tomas al día?

Normalmente la gente viaja por días o semanas, pero nosotros nos viajaremos por meses lo cual es algo inusual por lo que se usa el "dativo se" (nos) para indicarlo.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "viajar" is intransitive and is not pronominal. Therefore, only:

- Viajaremos unos meses.

is correct.

We can exceptionally use this verb with an aspectual dative to indicate intensity:

- Se viajó todo. (He traveled a lot)
- Se viajó la vida (same meaning)

Comment: So by this reasoning, would "Nos viajaremos mucho durante unos meses" be correct if we mean to say "We'll be traveling a lot for a few months"?

Comment: No, that sentence does not work. The sentences "se viajó todo" is a unit that does not admit an adverbial of duration. However, it does admit an adverbial of time: "Se viajó todo el año pasado" (He/She travelled a lot last year)

Answer (score 0):

The correct translation is *viajaremos unos meses*.

*viajarse* comes from something called *verbo pronominal*.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_pronominal

Comment: What does *viajarse* mean then? I thought it does not exist, but this answer seems to imply that it does.

Comment: According to the DLE https://dle.rae.es/viajar?m=form the verb only has intransitive uses and a rarer one which is transitive. There is not mention of a pronominal use there so you need to provide a source for your statement.